# What happens to default user files stored in D:/ when the drive fails?

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, user-accounts, restore, recovery

So, on my office pc (win10) I set my default user docs to be in D:/ and not in C:/. I worked like that for 8 years storing my design files predominantly in 1 folder "Design". This year my D:/ drive failed and I lost 480 gb of data. Now I tried to restore my files from D:/ but none of the files in this ONE folder is found. My question is what happened with files in this case and where are they? I tried 5 different restoring programs but I cannot find any of the files searching in D:/. I also searched in C:/ and nothing. It seem a bit strange how every file in such a big folder can be erased forever.....

PS: Please don't get me started with why I did not have a backup of that drive....

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “the D: drive failed”? Is the D: partition on a different physical drive? How exactly did it fail? What steps did you take to mitigate the failure? How are you searching for your list files?

Comment: No backup? No sympathy.

Comment: Yes, D:/ is a different drive. I don't know the exact reason the files were destroyed. It might have been power failure, but my files are gone as if the drive was formatted. I search for my missing files with software for files restoration, I don't know any better so far.
PS: I don't need sympathy, but some answers, thanks!

Comment: Did you try [MiniTool Data Recovery Software Free](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery-software/free-for-windows.html)?

Comment: Rather than risk further damage, take it to a data recovery specialist. Your question implies lack of technical knowledge, which increases risk disproportionately.

Comment: I did take it to 3 specialist who installed 3 different data recovery softwares and restored nothing. One of them actually made it worse by restoring corrupted files (not from the folder that I want) on the faulty drive. I'm ready to give up now, but still I wish I get some info to what happened to those files.

Comment: No recovery specialist is just going to run some app over your drive - they're going to take it apart & do it properly. Any 'specialist' who wrote data back to the drive you needed recovering has just killed your chances of recovery. You could investigate suing them for damages, but that's not going to get your data back now.

Comment: This is the company we have subscription service with, so I had to use them fisrt.

Comment: Well, now you know their 'expertise' is non-existent. They just removed *all* chance of recovery by writing to the drive you want recovered. That is an absolute no-no.

Comment: I am a designer and even I know that and yet this isn't making things better, is it? Is there a chance for my files to be stored also at another place or moved when the drive failed, after all the original path of these folders was C:/

Comment: No. There's no provision for files to suddenly decide to all move to another physical drive. Even if the machine 'forgot' & started writing to C it wouldn't retrospectively move any previously-saved data. You're clutching at straws now.

Comment: Yes I am, and I'm desperate because that's all my work. And I think it has to do with the fact that only the contents of this exact folder cannot be restored, while there were at least 20 other folders I got partially back!

Comment: Sorry, but you've been walking a tightrope without a safety net for 8 years, praying it doesn't break. It broke. You can give the drive to an *actual professional* recovery company, or just accept the losses & move on. No amount of desperation replaces adequate prior provision.

Comment: “Is there a chance for my files to be stored also at another place or moved when the drive failed” -No; The files are gone. If a data recovery company can recover the files depends on the type of drive failure. The drive functioning well enough to scan using consumer level data recovery tools is a good sign. Most data recovery companies only charge a initial fee if data recovery isn’t possible.  It sounds like data was recovered on the source drive, by doing that, they likely overwrote the data.

Comment: Alright! I start grieving process then...